# Write a stored procedure with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two stored procedures `spWeek` and `spMonth`.

I want to write one stored procedure such that when it is week1 or week2 or week3 -the first stored procedure i.e `spWeek` gets executed. Again when it is week4 - both the stored procedures i.e `spWeek` and `spMonth` get executed.

Please help me with the query to write the stored procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to know what week it is in the month?

Comment: What do you mean by week1 or week2?  When does the "week" change -- is it after 7 days from the first of the month?  Is it on Monday, is it on Saturday -- what happens in months that have more than 4 weeks?  There are many questions you are not addressing here -- this is why no one can answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will first calculate the week in the current month.

By substracting the week number of the last day in the previous month from the week number of the current date.

That number is used to control which procedures are executed.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spWeeklySometimesMonthly
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @week_in_month INT;
  SET @week_in_month = DATEPART(WEEK,GetDate())-DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(DAY,-DATEPART(DAY,GetDate()),GetDate()));

  IF (@week_in_month in (1,2,3,4))
  BEGIN
    exec spWeek;
  END;

  IF (@week_in_month = 4)
  BEGIN
    exec spMonth;
  END;

END
```

Do note that in Sql Server a week starts on Sunday.
So Saturday 2016-09-03 will have @week_in_month calculated as 0.
While Sunday 2016-09-04 calculates @week_in_month as 1.